# Is it possible to use snap while having sub division on

Tags: modeling

[image: Image 1]

When SubD is on it doesn't snap to the smoothed surface but rather uses the original surface on which the modifier is applied, in this image I used a cube to snap

[image: Image 2]

as you can see it snapped the Original surface

I faced this issue recently when modelling a interior because whenever I tried to snap a object it would always stay few mm above the snap surface, does anyone have any fix ?

Comment: If you haven't applied the modifier the new surface doesn't actually exist so snapping will only "see" the original geometry.

Comment: @JohnEason so you mean the only way is to either apply it or manually align it ?

Comment: Yes that's correct as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It works just fine for me, in fact I can't find a way to replicate what you have. The snapping geometry should always be what is *seen* in the viewport.  What are your snap settings?